# Interviewer asking for offer letter from current company for verification. How to proceed if I never got one?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, job-change

I am working in company A. Still I didn't get offer letter from company A since 1.3 years.

Now another (company B) interview is scheduled in 5 days. They will ask about my offer letter (issued by company A) for the document verification.

So when I go to the interview, what can I do? How to manage HR that still I didn't receive my offer letter?

Comment: What country? That could be important.

Comment: Show them a pay stub?

Comment: @Paparazzi that is the answer, sir IMHO.

Comment: Really I would just politely say "I never got one."  Possibly adding, "would you like to review my pay stubs?"  (1099s .. whatever).  **Don't make a big deal about it.**

Comment: @Fattie I never reveal how much I make as the new employer typically uses it as a starting point for negotiations.  IMO your worth what the market will pay.

Comment: What are they trying to achieve?  Are they just checking that you actually worked where you claim you worked?  That's part of what references are for.

Answer (score 7):

**If** they ask about the offer letter, just state that you don't have one.

Suggest them to call your current HR to verify employment; Maybe request them to call the HR **only after** issuing you a job offer, to avoid issues with your current employer once he knows you are job hunting.

Answer (score 3):

The country where this is happening could be important due to varying laws and customs. But I have to say that in general the Company B request for your original offer from Company A should be none of their business.

There are other suitable ways to verify your employment at Company A. One would be to show them a pay check stub. Although I feel that Company B really has no business knowing what your current rate of pay is either. Company B should be evaluating you on the basis of your CV/resume and the interview and then offering you a pay rate that they think is competitive for that job skill market.

Comment: None of their business.  They are just trying get a bead on the OP's salary I bet.

Comment: @MisterPositive - I agree totally. That is why I made the point of how they should determine the salary so that the OP can be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Your question does not have a country tag. However, from your name & from my experience, it look like India. If not, please let me know, I shall delete the answer.

The HR will ask you for your offer letter to verify 2 things:

1. That you really work for the company
2. You actually get the salary you mentioned

As paparazzi mentioned above, take your pay slips and your bank statement for 1.3 years.

In addition, since you have worked for 1.3 years, you would also have your govt. issued Form26AS from the tax portal, which mentions your net taxable income.

These 3 together will prove, beyond doubt that you work for the company and draw the salary you mentioned.

Also mention that you have not been issued with an offer letter from your company as yet.